# nlapiCreateRecord and nlapiLoadRecord throwing syntax error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am getting the following wherever I am using nlapiLoadRecord or nlapiCreateRecord in the suitescript(1.0):

```
"error": {
        "code": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
        "message": "syntax error (NLRecordScripting.scriptInit$lib#151)"
    }
```

Following is the code snippet

```
    if(datain.internalid != null){
        record = nlapiLoadRecord('supportcase',datain.internalid);
    }else{
        record = nlapiCreateRecord('supportcase');
    }
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a User Event running on `beforeLoad` that has an error in it; based on the error, I would look for a file containing a reference like `NLRecordScripting.scriptInit` on line 151.